# View Pager showing 2 out of 3 tabs, middle one not showing Android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I have 3 tabs, 3 listview fragments associated with the tabs and 2 of them are working the 1st and the 3rd, but the middle one isn't showing up and its not null b/c if I place its position at 0, itll show up.. which is weird... I wanted to know if anyone has experienced this and if its android bug.. give me some advice. thanks.

Here is some of the code:

This is the activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/assign"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/navbar_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabspager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_height="460dp">
 </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the main activity:

```
  public class main_activity extends AppCompatActivity implements  
  android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener{

  private ViewPager tabsviewPager;
  private ActionBar mActionBar;
 private TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

 tabsviewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.tabspager);

 mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

 tabsviewPager.setAdapter(mTabsAdapter);

getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

  ActionBar.Tab onestab = 
  getSupportActionBar().newTab().setText("one").setTabListener(this);
  ActionBar.Tab twotab = 
  getSupportActionBar().newTab().setText("two").setTabListener(this);
  ActionBar.Tab threetab = 
  getSupportActionBar().newTab().setText("three").setTabListener(this);

  getSupportActionBar().addTab(onestab);
  getSupportActionBar().addTab(twotab);
 getSupportActionBar().addTab(threetab);


//This helps in providing swiping effect for v7 compat library
tabsviewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new 
 ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});


}

 @Override
 public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

  @Override
 public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab selectedtab,
  FragmentTransaction arg1) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  tabsviewPager.setCurrentItem(selectedtab.getPosition()); 
 }

 @Override
 public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }
```

This is the tab adapter:

```
  public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

  private int TOTAL_TABS = 3;

 public TabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
  super(fm);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch (index) {
    case 0:
        return new oneFragment();

    case 1:
        return new twoFragment();

    case 2:
        return new threeFragment();
  }

 return null;
 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return TOTAL_TABS;
   }
   }
```

This is the fragment how I am setting it so it can go and show the listview when selected:

```
 public class twoFragment extends Fragment {

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.two_parent,   container, false);

     ListView View = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.testingView2);
     assignDB assignDB = new assignDB(getContext());
     List<TWO> assignData = assignDB.getAll();
     two_adapter adapter = new   two_adapter(getContext(), assignData);
    View.setAdapter(adapter);

     return view;
    }

   }
```

Comment: No error logs whatsoever, its so weird.. Also for some reason you have to hit the last tab for the first tab to be able to show visibility which is weird

Comment: Has anyone experienced this?? Or can help me